# javascript - Is it possible block xmlhttprequest function at server side?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I use `xmlhttprequest()` function on specific website for a few days and works great.

but suddenly `xmlhttprequest()` function return only `<head></head> <body></body>`.
I did not change any code on it

I can access website manually by clicking link.

Is it possible block only `xmlhttprequest` function at server side?
or just temporarily issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You can check the request headers when requesting the page via browser URL, and when requesting the page via `XMLHttpRequest`. Any difference in them will be identifiable by the server (and fixable by you, I think)

Comment: what status code is it returning?

Comment: I received `status = 200`

Comment: can you share the URL which you were hitting?

Comment: If you are hitting a URL from a different domain and if they have disabled CORs then you will get an error. CORs is generally disabled on the server side to prevent the requests coming from other domains.

Comment: [link](http://gall.dcinside.com/board/lists/?id=cat) I don't know whether can access on other area

Comment: I accessed same domain and it worked great. but almost 1 hour ago, suddenly blocked

Comment: `date: Sat, 18 Aug 2018 07:52:35 GMT
server: Apache
connection: Upgrade, close
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 0
vary: User-Agent
upgrade: h2,h2c
` here is ResponseHeader

Comment: I tested on other computer and it works fine. why this thing happen?

Comment: may be there is limit on this site to limit the request hit from a certain IP, if you are hitting too much. Try after some hours, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: Deleting the page's cookie made it work again.